# pm2 log output in real time

Tags: node.js, ruby, pm2

I'm trying to view logs of a running pm2 process in real-time.

When I run a js file, the output shows up in the log file as expected:

**test.js**

```
setInterval(function(){ console.log('FOO'); }, 1000);
```

However, if I try running a Ruby script, also writing to STDOUT, the log file does not get populated until after I stop the process:

**test.rb**

```
loop do
  puts "FOO"
  sleep 1
end
```

Comment: Why does this have the tag of node.js?

Comment: pm2 is nodejs process manager

Comment: start your pm2 by providing the interpreter `pm2 start test.rb --interpreter=ruby`.

Comment: Why? Makes no difference

Comment: @Yarin It seems to be a problem of pm2 with ruby script. I tested with node script and console log using `setInterval` and it's working fine.

Comment: @front_end_dev you're right, that's odd. Since they're both going to STDOUT. Adding the interpreter flag didn't help though. Not sure what's up.

Answer (score 0):

I know it was asked a long time ago but I've had the same problem.

What worked for me was adding a `STDOUT.flush` to assure ruby was writing immediately everything that stills pending.